# Half-Edge Data Structure with holes

Tags: c++, edge-detection

I am trying to implement next/prev of edges in half-edge data structure. But I ran into this question. If there are two holes with a common vertex, will the closed loop of the edges run as in the first picture? Or will it be two separate cycles, as in the second picture?

[image]

In 3ds Max, when the border tool is used, it selects the edge loop as in the first image. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

The cube-like mesh shown in the images is a non-manifold mesh. Officially half edge data structures do not support such a topology. However, this case can be supported by continuing the boundary half edges through the non-manifold node. This is apparently the way it is done in 3DS Max, and also Blender. You can look at [this](https://kaba.hilvi.org/homepage/blog/halfedge/halfedge.htm) article for several extension to the data structure to support non-manifold meshes.